# Map of string=>any (`require`)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ordereddictionary

I have a structure where I need ordered elements. Previously using an [`{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Server-side (Node.js).

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)s don't support arbitrary content, but I want string indexed rather than array. Alternatives?

#### gt.js

```
exports.gt = (a, b) => a > b;
```

#### lt.js

```
exports.lt = (a, b) => a < b;
```

#### operators.js

```
const operators = {lt: require('./lt'), gt: require('./gt')};
```

Approaches for ordered access:

```
// Option 0
const order = ['lt', 'gt'];
order.forEach(o => console.info(`option0::${o} =`, operators[o], ';'));

// Option 1
const operatorsList = [['lt', operators.lt], ['gt', operators.gt]];
console.info('option1::operatorsList =', operatorsList, ';');

// Option 2
const orderedMap = new Map(operatorsList);
console.info('option2::orderedMap =', orderedMap, ';');
```

Output:

```
option0::lt = { lt: [Function] } ;
option0::gt = { gt: [Function] } ;
option1::operatorsList = [['lt', {  lt: [Function]}],['gt', {  gt: [Function]}]] ;
option2::orderedMap = Map {'lt' => {lt: [Function]}, 'gt' => { gt: [Function]} } ;
```

That first option works and allows for efficient access, but the overhead for maintaining an external index is better avoided.

Comment: "Sets don't support arbitrary content" I do not believe this is accurate. MDN's docs state that Sets can contain values of any type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: I am using `Map`, but it doesn't support arbitrary output, like that from `require`.

Comment: Could you please post a complete example input and example output?

Comment: Sure thing, edited with that.

Comment: `require` is a blocking call, also a cached one. Its better if you could use a different logic that only `require`s once and use the exported functions multiple times!

Comment: It is unclear why a simple array does not work.  You want ordered access, that's what an array is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 of just using a `Map` actually does work and is able to store arbitrary content. Issue with my debugging is I was logging to `console` with `JSON.stringify` :\

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the order inside the value like this:

```js
const orderedObjects = {
  "somekey":{order: 0,value:"this is the first value"},
  "someotherkey":{order: 1,value:"this is the second value"},
  "anotherkey":{order: 2,value:"this is the third value"}
};
```

This solution does add some bloat, but it has worked fine for me in the past.

Comment: I suppose I could store an array of keys and a regular `{}` so that it would still be usable as a `string`=>`any`

Comment: @AT fyi `Object.keys(orderedObjects)` returns `["somekey","someotherkey","anotherkey"]`

Comment: Yes but I can't specify the order that that list has keys in.

Comment: @AT You can. Modern JS engines respect the order of keys in objects. Node is considered 'modern'. KISS principle is applicable here.